# Is the PayPal MEC library deprecated or discontinued?

Tags: paypal

I've successfully implemented the MEC pattern in a couple of native applications using the MECL library as described in:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices

The library (both iOS and Android packages) can be found here:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index?qt-paypal_sdk_index=2#qt-paypal_sdk_index

Unfortunately, the new http://developer.paypal.com website seem to have forgotten that once this library existed.

What should I do? Remove the library and do the express checkout without the DRT (device reference token) provided by the library? Or is it safe to still use it?

My app uses the DRT id to ask the server whether the payment was completed, and so a failure to get the token would compromise the ability to perform payments.

Comment: did you get any conclusion about your problem? I am having troubles to find the MEC library for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Express Checkout process is still around and available to use. There isn't any official code samples though and that is kind of a bummer.

You can use the Merchant SDK to get a working example of the full-site Express Checkout process and make changes to it as needed.

We're trying to get people to use the new iOS and Android SDK's.

Here is a link to a setup guide for Mobile Express Checkout:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices/

It goes into detail on the differences (mostly just the redirect URL) and I hope gets you a place to start.

Sorry!